# How to perform cy.type() for date-time input field

Tags: node.js, angularjs, cypress

I have an input tag as shown below:

```
<input aria-invalid="true" name="datetime" required="" type="date-time" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input MuiInputBase-inputAdornedEnd" value="____ __ __:__ _" xpath="1">
```

how can I pass date in cypress `.type()` command?
[image]

Comment: What's going wrong - can see a "2" there, did you `.type("2022-09-02")` and it didn't work?

Comment: @Fody Yes. I could type the date but it is showing me an invalid format error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `.realType()` instead.

See [realType()](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events#cyrealtype)

This command has `delay` and `pressDelay` built in.

Install the package [cypress-real-events](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events) and add the following line at the top of the spec, or in `cypress/support/e2e.js`.

```js
import "cypress-real-events/support"
```

Then the command is just

```js
cy.get(myInput).focus()
cy.realType('2022-09-02')
```

If still no luck, you will have to take a look at the event behind the input. Looks like you're in Firefox, so click on the event tag next to the element and see if there's any clues in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a delay with `type` command like this. So now there would be a delay of 30 ms after each keypress.

```js
cy.get('input[name="datetime"]').type('2022-09-02', {delay: 30})
```